# problema con JSON al retonar un id

Tags: json, integer

Estimados me presento a esta gran comunidad, siempre busco ayuda aqui pero es primera vez que me veo forzado a publicar una solicitud, desde ya agradezco a quienes puedan respinderme.

mi problema es que esty obteniendo este error al ejecutar un JSON

> javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Error getting value on:
>   root.persistence.entities.Producto[ idproductos=1 ]

y no entiendo muy bien el porque, estoy trabajando con netbeans pero deployando en heroku a una base postgress las pruebas las estoy realizando con postman

mi archivo de persistencia es el siguiente.

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package root.persistence.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author rodrigo
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "productos")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Producto.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Producto p")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Producto.findByIdproductos", query = "SELECT p FROM Producto p WHERE p.idproductos = :idproductos")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Producto.findByNombre", query = "SELECT p FROM Producto p WHERE p.nombre = :nombre")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Producto.findByDetalle", query = "SELECT p FROM Producto p WHERE p.detalle = :detalle")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Producto.findByPrecio", query = "SELECT p FROM Producto p WHERE p.precio = :precio")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Producto.findByDescuento", query = "SELECT p FROM Producto p WHERE p.descuento = :descuento")})
public class Producto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "idproductos")
    private Integer idproductos;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "detalle")
    private String detalle;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "precio")
    private BigInteger precio;
    @Column(name = "descuento")
    private BigInteger descuento;

    public Producto() {
    }

    public Producto(Integer idproductos) {
        this.idproductos = idproductos;
    }

    public Producto(Integer idproductos, String nombre, String detalle, BigInteger precio) {
        this.idproductos = idproductos;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.detalle = detalle;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public Integer getIdproductos() {
        return idproductos;
    }

    public void setIdproductos(Integer idproductos) {
        this.idproductos = idproductos;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDetalle() {
        return detalle;
    }

    public void setDetalle(String detalle) {
        this.detalle = detalle;
    }

    public BigInteger getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(BigInteger precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public BigInteger getDescuento() {
        return descuento;
    }

    public void setDescuento(BigInteger descuento) {
        this.descuento = descuento;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idproductos != null ? idproductos.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Producto)) {
            return false;
        }
        Producto other = (Producto) object;
        if ((this.idproductos == null && other.idproductos != null) || (this.idproductos != null && !this.idproductos.equals(other.idproductos))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "root.persistence.entities.Producto[ idproductos=" + idproductos + " ]";
    }

    public String getProducto() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

y la llamada a la API la genero desde la clase Producto que es esta

```
package root.services;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import root.persistence.entities.Producto;

@Path("/productos")
public class ProductosREST {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("UP_Productos");
    EntityManager em;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response listarTodo(){
        try{
        em =emf.createEntityManager();

        List<Producto> lista = em.createNamedQuery("Producto.findAll").getResultList();


        return Response.ok().entity(lista).build();
        }catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            em.close();
                    return Response.ok(500).entity("Error- no se logro listar los productos").build();

        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{idbuscar}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response buscarId(@PathParam("idbuscar") Integer idbuscar) {
        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            Producto producto = em.find(Producto.class, idbuscar);
            return Response.ok(producto).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            em.close();
        }

        return Response.ok(500).entity("Error- no se logro buscar el producto por id").build();
    }
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String nuevo(Producto productoNuevo) {

        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(productoNuevo);
            em.getTransaction().commit();

            return "Producto Guardado";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error al guardar el Producto: ";
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }

    }

    @PUT
    public Response actualizar(Producto productoUpdate) {
        String resultado = null;

        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            productoUpdate = em.merge(productoUpdate);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            return Response.ok("Producto actualizado OK").build();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            String id = productoUpdate.getProducto();

            if (id == null) {
                return Response.ok("no existe id de producto").build();
            }

        } finally {

            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
        return Response.ok(resultado).build();
    }
      @DELETE
    @Path("/{iddelete}")
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response eliminaId(@PathParam("iddelete") Integer iddelete) {

        try { 

            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Producto productoEliminar = em.getReference(Producto.class, iddelete);
            em.remove(productoEliminar);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            return Response.ok("Producto eliminado").build();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return Response.ok("Error al eliminar").build();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }

    }
}
```

y mi xml de persistencia lo he configurado asi.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he probado varias formas pero el error persiste, desde ya agradezco su invaluable ayuda.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. ¿Puedes confirmar que estás recibiendo el JSON correctamente? ¿Podrías por favor mostrar la estructura del JSON que estás recibiendo?

Comment: puedes validar la estructura del json aquí https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: me aparece el siguiente error   URL returned bad status code 500.

Comment: pero al hacerlo con postman me aparece el siguiente mensaje: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Error getting value on: root.persistence.entities.Producto[ idproductos=1 ]

Comment: Entonces si recibes un error code 500 significa que hay algún problema en el servidor, mientras eso no se corrija no veo forma de poder trabajar con el JSON. ¿El código de servidor depende de ti? Revisa lo que está mal. Si depende de otra persona debes ponerte en contacto con esa persona e informarte sobre la forma correcta de consultar los datos de ese servidor.

Comment: mm claro pero a que peude deberse el error "error getting value on: root.persistence.entities.Producto[ idproductos=1 ]" ya que tenbgo la impresion de que si conecta y si va a buscar el metodo y este retorna pero al momento de convertirlo en jason algo pasa en la clase de entidad y se cael el json

Comment: Favor cerrar, o marcar como solucionado encontré la solución, me faltaba agregar el driver de postgress en el pom